# Python script won't run in bash script, but works fine in cmd prompt

Tags: python, bash, cmd

I have a python script that I want to automate so I created a simple bash script (called mybash.sh).

```
#!/bin/sh

vars="C:\Users\Jane\Desktop\Work\variables.csv"

while IFS="," read gname gid
do
    echo "Gene Name: $gname"
    echo "Gene ID: $gid"
    python alignment.py work_file $gid > C:\\Users\\Jane\\Desktop\\Work_Done\\$gname.fa
done < "$vars"

read -rn1
```

It is a huge script but I always get an error saying that the last line of my alignment.py script has a NameError, so after running my bash script from windows cmd prompt as >mybash.sh I get this:

```
Gene Name: cytb   
Gene ID: ENSB0010011
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alignment.py", line 99, in <module>
    for species in geneDict:
NameError: name 'geneDict' is not defined
```

The geneDict is the very last part of the python script which simply creates a fasta alignment file for a gene for all species in separate folder.
When I execute the python script normally in cmd prompt, it works perfectly fine but instead of extracting the gname (gene name) and gid (gene ID) from a variables file, I was typing it manually. I didn't want to do that for 200 genes. I can't understand why it no longer finishes and says that the geneDict is no longer defined?

Also, I tried making the python script run in a bash script alone as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

python alignment.py work_file ENSB0010011 > C:\\Users\\Jane\\Desktop\\Work_Done\\cytb.fa
```

And this worked fine also, the python script did not stop working all of a sudden and my file came out. How do I make the python script execute without error, while pulling the variables from variables.csv separately so that I don't have to type it in manually?

The last bit of the python script is as follows:

```
for species in geneDict:    # this is where it says geneDict is not defined
    print '>' + species
    print geneDict[species]
```

Comment: None of the code you provide here defines `geneDict`

Comment: Yea the rest of the code is long and also isn't entirely my work so I don't know if I was able to post it without their permission (and unfortunately they are away at the moment so I will have to ask them when they come back). The script itself works fine. I am just having trouble running it through a bash. The bash part is what I am confused about.

Comment: @DNAngel A note about the shebang `#!/bin/sh` in bash script file. This shebang means run this script with `sh` in root subdirectory `bin`. On many Linux distributions file `sh` in `/bin` is a symbolic link to shell interpreter `bash`, but can also link to `sh` or `ksh` or ... You might use `#!/bin/bash` to explicitly require the interpretation of this shell script by shell interpreter `bash`. But I really don't know how is predefined the Unix environment and which shebang should be used on Windows.

Comment: @DNAngel I suggest to make sure that the script file most likely written on Windows with a Windows text editor contains only line-feed as line ending (Unix style) and not carriage return + line-feed as standard on Windows. Sometimes shell scripts do not work as expected if the shell script contains CR+LF as [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). I doubt that this is the cause of the issue here, but it is nevertheless advisable to save the shell script with just LF as line terminator. Is `alignment.py` stored with LF or with CR+LF?

Answer (score 1):

NameError exception is raised because global variable "geneDict" is not defined in python script. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError

Comment: It is defined earlier, I just didn't post the whole code for my comment above. I didn't write it and I didn't want to post it without the other person's permission - but the code itself works fine when I run it by itself. It only has an error when I try to automate it in bash.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the python script itself just not work at all from the start if that error was coming up?

Comment: I do not know if it is defined or not but that's what exception does tell us.

Comment: The script will execute line by line from the top until an exception is raised.

Comment: But if I run it where I just type the variables individually, I don't get that exception at all. I would think it would still come up regardless of how I was executing it? So I don't understand why in a bash script I suddenly get that error when it never showed up before.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong in bash script. I can not help you with that. However, it is so simple to do it in python what you are trying to do in bash script.

Comment: Yea I have no idea how to do the same thing in python, I can only understand automating something repetitive using a bash script.